# What does the formula $\;(X_i,Y_i)\sim p_{X,Y}\;$ mean? How can it be read?

Tags: statistics, notation

What does $(X_i,Y_i)\sim p_{X,Y}$ mean? How can be read it?

I know that the left-hand side has coordinates, but is the right-hand side the probability of $X$ and Y? What does it mean?

CONTEXT:
Using Mutual Information to judge whether two variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent or not. We record $n$ pairs $(X_i, Y_i)\sim p_X$, $i=\{1,...,n\}$ independently (data).

Comment: My interpretation is that the joint random variable(s) $(X_i,Y_i)$ have a distribution dictated by the pmf/pdf $p_{X,Y}$

Comment: is there a typo in the context paragraph, you mean $P_{X,Y}$ right?